# EF Core 2.1 with Seed method and NotMapped attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, seeding

I have a question, why my `Strategy` property is null, when i getting all `DbSet` from context? How to `[NotMapped]` property make visible in my backend?

My class looks like this:

```
public class Machine
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public WorkStrategy Strategy { get; set; }

    public double GetManHours() => Strategy.TimeOfWork(HoursPerDay);
}
```

`WorkStrategy` is an abstract class:

```
public abstract class WorkStrategy
{
    public abstract double TimeOfWork(double hours);
}

public class FarmStrategy : WorkStrategy
{
    public override double TimeOfWork(double hours) => // do things
}

public class CultivationStrategy : WorkStrategy
{
    public override double TimeOfWork(double hours) => //do things
}
```

Part of my `Seed` method where i seeding machines looks like this:

```
//Machines
for(int i = 0; i < countOfMachines; i++)
{
    Machine machine = new Machine { Id = i + 1 };
    machine.Strategy = new FarmStrategy;
    modelBuilder.Entity<Machine>().HasData(machine);
}
```

But when i call `Machines` from DB:

```
var machines = _context.Machines;
```

The `Strategy` property is null. Could you tell me, how to attach `[NotMapped]` property while seeding a db
? Is it possbile?

**EDIT**

When i want to add `WorkStrategy` as not "notmapped" i get an error from EF while i adding migration:

> The entity type 'WorkStrategy' requires a primary key to be defined

But i dont want to make an table for WorkStrategy.

**EDIT**
My `OnModelCreating` in `context` class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Machine>().Ignore(x => x.Strategy);

        builder.Seed();
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
```

Its not work as `[NotMapped]`

Comment: not mapped attribute says "ignore this property if mapping from db context". You need populate it yourself.

Comment: You dont need create new table for workStrategy if you will use as Value object. Look for Value object and [Owned] attribute it may be what you want.

Comment: If you have the `NotMapped` attribute then you shouldn't be getting that error message. Have you used that model elsewhere perhaps? Maybe it's even a `DbSet<WorkStrategy>`?

Comment: @DavidG sorry, when i deleted [NotMapped] i get that massege, edited

Comment: So do you want the `Strategy` property to be in the database or not? I'm confused now.

Comment: To be honest, it doesnt matter for my purpose. I just want to attach that `Strategy` to `Machine` From seed Method. I want to have acces to it in my code by `dbContext`. If it is impossible to do it with Seed method, i will make it somewhere in code.

Comment: @daremachine it looks promising, but when i add `[Owned]` property on `WorkStrategy` its still null i `_context`

Comment: "Seeding" is the process of putting the data into the database, if you don't want it in the database then you don't seed it.

Comment: I think this is a [XY Problem ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fluent api ignore instead of notmapped

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Machine>().Ignore(x => x.Strategy );
```

Comment: @michasaucer Why did you accept the answer when it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I think your Problem is not the not mapped Attribute, but the Structure of your Classes.
If you had a Flag, which Type of Strategy is needed and adapt the Strategy-Property depending on that Flag to initialize a Strategy if it’s null, you could keep your Notmapped-Attribute or the Ignore-Method with Fluent-Api.